# z3c 5803 Lollipop 5.1.1 rooted -> TWRP Factor Reset -> Now Philz Touch 6 instead of TWRP

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, twrp, clockworkmod-recovery, sony-xperia-z3

I used TWRP to make a backup ( with the default options ) to make a backup to my external SDCard.

Then I used TWRP to perform a default factory reset

[image]

I did not manually touch anything else. I booted my android to check if I got a factory reset but I did not wipe anything else or install anything.

If I now boot into recovery I see "Philz Touch 6

[image]

Now I am confused, normally at this point I saw the TWRP GUI ?

Is TWRP still on my phone
Why is Philz Touch there now ?

PS: This was the first time I used the key combination to boot into recovery.
Before the factory reset I used the app "quick boot" to boot into recovery.

[image]

But I assume both methods ( app and physical buttons ) have the same results.

So my Question is where is TWRP after I performed a TWRP Factory Reset ?

Comment: I see on XDA that your device has custom recoveries that can host both TWRP and Phil's. Did you flash such a recovery? (Most likely). In that case it's better to go through the recovery forum and you may find the reason. You can always post the findings here :)

Comment: Yes, under http://nut.xperia-files.com/html/xzdualrecovery-manual.html I could find that I have both recoveries and that there are different key combinations to launch either of them

Answer (score 0):

After the comment above `I see on XDA that your device has custom recoveries that can host both TWRP and Phil's` I searched my windows PC for the installation file that I flashed to install TWRP. The filename is *XZDualRecovery*

Google then gave me this [link](http://nut.xperia-files.com/html/xzdualrecovery-manual.html) having the manual

This means I have both PhilZ Touch AND TWRP installed.

I solved my problem by the correct key combination during startup:

- press <kbd>VOL-UP</kbd> for PhilZ Touch;
- press <kbd>VOL-DOWN</kbd> for TWRP.